# How do I get $entity in hook_form_alter()?

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

`hook_add_form()` gets `$entity_type` and `$entity` as parameters, but `hook_form_alter()` does not have any of those parameters.

How do I get the entity type and the entity object in `hook_form_alter()`in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that it should be possible to do something like this.

```
if ($form_state->getFormObject() instanceof \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormInterface) {
  $entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  $entity_type = $entity->bundle();
}
```

UPDATE: In Drupal 7 it should be done like this:

```
$node = $form['#entity_type']; // E.g this could be, (#node, #user etc.)
```

Take a look at this site, [drupal discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/1734556).

Comment: You may also want an if like in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/213156/48114) to make sure you're operating on an entity form before making these calls.

Comment: Oh sorry guys I am working with Drupal 7 and forgot to mention in hurry :(. Any way similar functions work with D7? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Yes this will work! Thank you a lot!!! Saved me a ton of time.

Comment: Nice I'm glad that it worked :)

Comment: This isn't right - nodes are just one type of entity, you'll never find any other type of entity in `$form['node']`

Comment: Well I need commerce_product entity from hook_form_alter() actually. I am working on adding a button to add_to_cart form with functionality but I need access to entity.

Comment: Thank you @Clive, I see, I have updated the answer to display it more clearly.

Comment: THat's fine for the type, but how do you get the entity object itself?

Comment: @Jdrupal See my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Entity types each implemented their own form in D7, there wasn't a generic one. You're at the mercy of what the author of each bit of code decided at the time.

For example you can find consistency with *some* of the core entity types:

- node -> `$form['#node']`
- user -> `$form['#user']`
- comment -> `$form['#comment']`

But not all the way through:

- taxonomy_term -> `$form['#term']`

You might find it easier to target the specific types of entity you're interested in, determine what the correct array key is for each, and store them in a map somewhere for later access.