# How to access paragraph fields from a webform's form?

Tags: webforms, 9, paragraphs

I have a webform (*contact_info*) which is attached to a paragraph's field (*field_contact_info*). The paragraph has other fields as well.

I implemented `hook_form_alter()` to change some attributes inside the webform's form.

Is there any way to access the values of other paragraph fields value in `hook_form_alter()`?

I can pass them inside the webform object, but those aren't available in `hook_form_alter()` or the form array.

Any help on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get $entity in hook\_form\_alter()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260843/how-do-i-get-entity-in-hook-form-alter)

Comment: Sorry that is completely different issue. If I get the entity inside hook_form_alter(), it will return webform object not the paragraph.

Comment: This is quite the same issue. Once you have the host entity for the form, you can query whatever entity and whatever field you want. Remember Webform has a [getSourceEntity()](https://github.com/drupalprojects/webform/blob/e5a82adbdd323b5aa506f5226adf15dd1d7e9b11/src/Plugin/WebformSourceEntityManager.php#L41)

Comment: Ah! you are absolutely correct!! You made my day. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi @Hudri, Would you submit the answer? Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered by @hudri

inside the hook_form_alter() get the entity first:

```
if ($form_state->getFormObject() instanceof \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormInterface) {
  $entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
}
```

Then get the parent paragraph using this

```
$entity->getSourceEntity()
```

This will return the paragraph instance with all the fields.